# LastPass - What exactly does this do "Respect AutoComplete=off: allow websites to disable Autofill"

Tags: lastpass

It's a setting inside LastPass. There are settings where you can turn on and off autofill, but I have no idea what this does. I'd appreciate it if someone could educate me on this.

Answer (score 0):

If a website uses something like this:

```
<input type="password" id="passwordP" class="form-inputText"
 placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off" onfocus="pwdFocusP();">
```

Note the `autocomplete` keyword.
If you leave that option

> Respect AutoComplete=off: allow websites to disable Autofill

in LastPass off it supposedly will not respect the site developer's request for a manual entry (or copy/paste of the value).